# jquery и js, можно ли совмещать их синтаксис и писать в одном файле?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня такая ситуация, делал корзину товаров для сайта на jquery, и теперь там же после кода на jquery пишу js, будут ли какие то проблемы из за этого ?
Вот код:

```js
var newprice, tovarid, allprice, price;
var newcount = 0;
var id;
var result = document.getElementById("result");

var info = [newprice, id, newcount];
var key = 'ruso_q_712899_example';

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.add-tovar').click(function(){
allprice = $('#cart span#price').attr("price");
price = $(this).attr("price");
tovarid = $(this).attr("rel");
newprice = Number(allprice) + Number(price);
newcount++;
$('#cart span#price').html(newprice+' руб. ').attr("price",newprice);
$('#cart span.count').html(newcount);
$(document).mousemove(function(pos){
$('.messagecart').css("left",(pos.pageX+10)+'px').css("top",            
(pos.pageY+10)+"px");
});
$(".messagecart").html("Добавляю...").show();
/*$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "addcart.php",
datatype: "html",
data: "id="+tovarid,
success: function(data){
    $("#test2").html("Добавлено");
    setTimeout('$("messagecart").hide();',600);
}
})*/
    $("#test").click(function (e){
    $("#test2").html(Number(newprice) + " rub").attr("allprice",newprice);
    })
})
})
function tot(){ //проверка
console.log(newprice + " 111");
}

function addarr(){ //заполение массива
for (var i =0; i<info.length; i++) {
    info[i] = tovarid;
}
}
$("#sendbtn").click(function() {
window.localStorage[key] = info; //*
getMessageFromLocalStorage();
})

// Приём сообщения
function getMessageFromLocalStorage() {
result.textContent = window.localStorage[key];
}
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {
if (event.key !== key) {
    return;  // Если прислали не наши данные, ничего не делаем
}
getMessageFromLocalStorage();
});
getMessageFromLocalStorage();
```

Comment: Вы определённо сделали мой день :) Или это троллинг?

Comment: @Aid не думаю, человек и правда не понимает. Вызвано скорее всего тем, что часто противопоставляют jQuery чистому js.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, тогда положение дел о новичках ещё более плачевно, чем я ожидал. Лучше надеяться на троллинг.

Comment: Я просто не могу понять почему проблема в коде и пытаюсь найти причину. В современном js слишком много понтов и усложнений, на этом фоне простые вещи выглядят сложными, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Answer (score 2):

Никаких проблем не будет. jQuery - это библиотека на javascript.

Фактически, у вас всегда работает javascript. А код jQuery - просто вызовы функций сторонней библиотеки.

Comment: То есть если у меня не работает код, это только в коде проблема, конфликта у переменных и функций никаких не будет ? И я могу спокойно в jquery вставлять обычные функции на чистом js и использовать их ?

Comment: Конфликта как такового нет. Можете использовать и то, и другое.

Comment: @ВладиславДементьев конфликт будет если вы его сами себе устроите :-)

Comment: Спасибо, видимо создал сам себе. В данном коде браузер ругается что переменная result содержит null, то есть в функции приема сообщения в нее null записывается ? почему так может быть ?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, задайте его отдельно.

Comment: @ВладиславДементьев, это значит что такого элемента на странице нет, возможно вы вызываете код до формирования DOM структуры. Либо добавьте код в коллбэк на window.onload, либо оберните код в $(function () {/*...вашкод*/} )

Comment: @ВладиславДементьев _То есть если у меня не работает код_ - то его нужно отлаживать. Ради бога, не нужно гадать и лазить по форумам, отладка, отладка и ещё раз отладка - в которой на каждом шаге проверяем, что каждая строчка сработала правильно. Вам для этого уже во все браузеры и в IE средства разработчика вставили, попробуйте их, они классные.

Comment: Я задал этот вопрос потому что инспектор ошибок пишет всякую ересь, в хроме и мозиле пишет разные ошибки, в хроме вообще такое ощущение что для 50 ошибок есть 1 ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Разницы, конечно, никакой нет, но.. Лучше отделять их дуг от друга, хотя бы вот так:

```
//\\//\\//\\//\\ End jQuery Calls //\\//\\//\\//\\
```

Чтоб самому потом не запутаться. А еще лучше в другой файл перенести.

Comment: Я бы лучше рекомендовал изучить jQuery получше, стараться сделать код простым и понятным, отформатировать его, а также осилить отладку в средствах разработчика браузера. А, раз уж используется jquery, так идем до конца - никаких getElementById. B вообще, поставить себе любую IDE, netbeans например, где будет при каждом чихе документацию на js/jquery показывать. Писать в блокноте сейчас - это как программировать на перфокартах. Круто и бессмысленно.

Comment: sublime очень легкий и удобный, отладчика в нем увы нет конечно, попробую netbeans, спасибо за совет.